# Password Based Encryption with Social Login

Tags: passwords, password-management, oauth2

I have a question about implementing user password-based encryption in a database injunction with the Social Login feature.
User **private data** in my database should be **encrypted** in order to provide security at rest, and for that, I'm planning to use a **user password-derived key**.

Also, my application will need the Social Login function (Google, Facebook, etc). In the case of user registration through the Social Login, he **will not** provide a password to encrypt with (It is **required** not to complicate user registration, so I can't request a password myself).
There are my thoughts:

1. Use some **"default" password**, defined in the application server (bad, in case of application server breach it will be hacked immediately)
2. Derive password from **some info**, provided by Social Login. User Id maybe? (bad, it is public information)

So, my question is - **what** can I use to encrypt user data in the case of Social Login registration?

Comment: You explain why you want to have such encryption in general but not what it should protect from ("security at rest" is not a threat description). If you aim is to derive the encryption key from something only the user knows (i.e. password)  then you definitely need something only known to the user  - and social login does not provide this to you.

Comment: Doesn't the system need to read the private data? Or it is only relevant to the user?

Comment: 1) What will you do if user changes password? 2) Think of [Kerckhoffs's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle): You should assume that an attacker know everything about the user except the password and will be able to derive the same password as you.

Comment: @mentallurg the first one easy with the usual [Key Encryption key](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/75022/18298)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Simply Ask the User

Ask them if they would like to encrypt their data with a password or private key. If a user has registered with you directly, instead of some third-party authentication service, you can also offer to encrypt with the user password.

You could also hide this in a settings menu. Users who don't know what that means or don't care won't be bothered by it, while more security conscious users will likely go the extra way.